# What is the most efficient way to create an N-times-a-character string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have a char ('`-`') and a number (`80`) of times it should be repeated in a string.
I need to get a string of that char repeated given number of times:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I know I can do `result += myChar` x N times in a loop. I don't think it is very efficient. Is there a better way to do that?

By the most efficient I mean: **fastest**

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsperf.com/zerofill-any and replace "0" with your character.

Comment: You an do `(new Array(81)).join('-')` if you want something short that doesn't explicitly code a loop. (But I would assume `.join()` is implemented with a loop.) You can test the performance versus a loop for yourself at http://jsperf.com.

Comment: @nnnnnn the binary tree method is good, but if an upper limit to the length is known, you can just store a global string of 80 dashes and take substrings. You won't get faster than that. Similarly, a function which generates the string could cache the resulting string and only generate further when needed.

Comment: sorry that should have been @kalley

Comment: Best way to do something is not a good fit for SO...

Comment: @kalley I had a go at implementing my optimisation on that page. It's much faster when the length is sufficient that caching matters (I tried 30), but slower otherwise (as you'd expect) http://jsperf.com/zerofill-any/2

Comment: @bonomo Because questions about the best way "[...] will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask Make your question specific about what aspect you actually would like to improve. Otherwise it's too open ended and a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the best I could come up with, after a couple minutes playing, is:

```
String.prototype.repeat = function (len) {
    return (new Array(len + 1)).join(this);
}

console.log('-'.repeat(5));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SsRS9/1/).

Which is, unfortunately, cheapened a little as [@nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196741/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-an-n-times-a-character-string-in-javascript/18196826#comment26667381_18196741) commented with the correct answer two minutes beforehand. Sigh...